# First order derivative of inner product w.r.t. vector

Tags: partial-derivative

Let $\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{y}\in\Bbb{R}^m$, and $A\in\Bbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Also, let $f\colon\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = \big(A\mathbf{x}\big)\cdot\mathbf{y} = \big(A\mathbf{x}\big)^\top\mathbf{y}
$$
What is the first derivative of $f$ (which will belong to $\Bbb{R}^n$) with respect to $\mathbf{x}$, i.e.,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{x}}=\frac{\partial(A\mathbf{x})^\top\mathbf{y}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}=?
$$

Will it be just 
$$
\frac{\partial(A\mathbf{x})^\top\mathbf{y}}{\partial\mathbf{x}} = A^\top\mathbf{y},
$$

or something else? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you tried writing this out in coordinates to develop a sense of the answer? Then you'll probably see a more elegant proof.

Comment: Actually I did, but I would like some confirmation, as I am not sure...

Comment: Yes, $A^Ty$ is the correct expression for the gradient of $f(x).\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks right as for vectors over $\mathbb{R}^j$,

$$Ax \cdot y = y \cdot Ax  = y^TAx = (A^Ty)^T x$$

Comment: Could you explain your notation please? Because I can only guess what you want to say!

Comment: Updated notation so it's hopefully now more consistent with your original post

Comment: Right, that makes perfect sense! I should have seen that too! Thanks a lot!